# Problem in CiviMail after upgrade of CiviCRM 4.5.4 to 4.7.10 in Joomla 2.5.28

Tags: civimail, joomla, angular, 4.7.10

I have recently upgraded CiviCRM 4.5.4 to 4.7.10 latest stabled version.

I can't select any recipients from CiviMail recipient dropdown, when I select a group, the field label goes red and it display error message like "No recipients".

Some user experience the similar problem most of them are solved the issue by uninstalling of K2 plugin. But in my case I'm not using K2 plugin in my installation.

I have also tried deprecated UI by adding " define('CIVICRM_CIVIMAIL_UI_LEGACY',1); " in civicrm.settings.php and it is also not worked.

Below I have mentioned the error displayed in console:

```
Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
**TypeError: b.indexOf is not a function**
    at d.b (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:6988)
    at d.initContainerWidth (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:7172)
    at d.initContainer (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:13014)
    at d.init (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:1:19472)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:31028)
    at Function.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:2975)
    at m.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:835)
    at m.a.fn.select2 (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:30773)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=xnu4d:412:11)
    at Function.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:2975) '<' input crm-entityref="{entity: 'Campaign', select: {allowClear: true, placeholder: ts('Select Campaign')}}" crm-ui-id="subform.campaign" name="campaign" ng-model="mailing.campaign_id" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-isolate-scope crm-form-entityref crm-campaign-ref crm-ajax-select" id="crmUiId_4" tabindex="-1" title="{{crmUiField.title}}*" '>'
**TypeError: b.indexOf is not a function**
    at d.b (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:6988)
    at d.initContainerWidth (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:7172)
    at d.initContainer (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:13014)
    at d.init (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:1:19472)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:31028)
    at Function.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:2975)
    at m.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:835)
    at m.a.fn.select2 (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:30773)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=xnu4d:412:11)
    at Function.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:2975) '<' select crm-ui-id="subform.msg_template_id" name="msg_template_id" class="fa-clipboard ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope" crm-ui-select="{dropdownAutoWidth : true, allowClear: true, placeholder: ts('Message Template')}" ng-model="mailing.msg_template_id" ng-change="loadTemplate(mailing, mailing.msg_template_id)" id="crmUiId_5" tabindex="-1" title="{{crmUiField.title}}*" '>'
**TypeError: b.indexOf is not a function**
    at d.b (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:6988)
    at d.initContainerWidth (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:7172)
    at d.initContainer (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:13014)
    at d.init (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:1:19472)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:31028)
    at Function.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:2975)
    at m.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:835)
    at m.a.fn.select2 (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:30773)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=xnu4d:412:11)
    at Function.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:2975) '<'select crm-ui-id="subform.fromAddress" crm-ui-select="{dropdownAutoWidth : true, allowClear: false, placeholder: ts('Email address')}" name="fromAddress" ng-model="fromPlaceholder.label" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope" id="crmUiId_6" tabindex="-1" title="{{crmUiField.title}}*" '>'
**TypeError: b.indexOf is not a function**
    at d.b (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:6988)
    at d.initContainerWidth (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:7172)
    at d.initContainer (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:13014)
    at d.init (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:1:19472)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:31028)
    at Function.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:2975)
    at m.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:835)
    at m.a.fn.select2 (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:30773)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=xnu4d:412:11)
    at Function.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:2975) '<'select crm-ui-id="subform.replyTo" crm-ui-select="{dropdownAutoWidth : true, allowClear: true, placeholder: ts('Email address')}" name="replyTo" ng-change="checkReplyToChange(mailing)" ng-model="mailing.replyto_email" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope" id="crmUiId_7" tabindex="-1" title="{{crmUiField.title}}*" '>'
**TypeError: b.indexOf is not a function**
    at d.b (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:6988)
    at d.initContainerWidth (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:7172)
    at d.initContainer (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:22710)
    at d.init (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:1:19472)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:31028)
    at Function.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:2975)
    at m.each (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:835)
    at m.a.fn.select2 (http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2:30773)
    at link (http://<domain>.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=xnu4d:3060:20)
    at http://<domain>.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=xnu4d:70:93 '<'select crm-mailing-recipients="" ng-model="mailing.recipients" crm-mandatory-groups="crmMailingConst.groupNames | filter:{is_hidden:1}" crm-avail-groups="crmMailingConst.groupNames | filter:isMailingList | filter:{is_hidden:0}" crm-avail-mailings="crmMailingConst.civiMails" crm-ui-id="{{crmMailingBlockRecipients.id}}" name="{{crmMailingBlockRecipients.name}}" ng-required="true" multiple="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope" id="crmUiId_8" tabindex="-1" '>'
**TypeError: b.indexOf is not a function**
    at d.b (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at d.initContainerWidth (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at d.initContainer (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at d.init (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:1)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)
    at m.each (jquery.js:136)
    at m.a.fn.select2 (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (Common.js?r=xnu4d:412)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)
**TypeError: b.indexOf is not a function**
    at d.b (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at d.initContainerWidth (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at d.initContainer (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at d.init (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:1)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)
    at m.each (jquery.js:136)
    at m.a.fn.select2 (select2.min.js?r=xnu4d:2)
    at ?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=xnu4d:2128
    at angular.js:16414
```

Comment: I believe I have a similar problem- Clean new installation of CiviCRM 4.7.10 on a fresh installation of Joomla 3.6.2. I've added a number of contacts, in several groups. Creating an email in Civimail: when adding a group as recipients, from the dropdown list, it is added, green, but the yellow box to the right says "No recipients", and it is not sent to anyone. Triple checking the group - there are members in the groups, with email addresses. What to check or try? Magnus

Comment: Best to try in the demo.civicrm.org to make sure it isn't a real bug in the codebase first. If it working there then we can continue on with troubleshooting. I'm familiar with Joomla. Also, do you have a backtrace? Go to ~/media/civicrm/ConfigandLogs find the latest log. Copy the backtrace listing after you perform the function that isn't working for you.